# Working with a SqlXml parameter in a SQLCLR method

Tags: c#, t-sql, xpath, xquery, sqlclr

This is SQL CLR, I'm just trying to create a function that receives XML from SQL and then gets the value for a certain node and returns it:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString FnGetQuoteNumber(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            string nodeValue = null;

            xmlDoc.Load(xmlDoc.ToString());

            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Identifier[@name='Item1']");

            if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement != null)
            {
                nodeValue = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
            }

            return new SqlString(nodeValue);
        }
```

But then I realized, shouldn't my parameter be declared as `SqlXml xmlDoc` rather than `XmlDocument xmlDoc`?

If that's the case, then I cannot do the above because I'm not dealing with an `XmlDocument` anymore (there's no `DocumentElement`/`selectSingleNode`, etc).

**What would be the correct way to do this for `SqlXml`s?**

Also, when I try to deploy this, I keep getting this (which I think has to do with the `XmlDocument` I'm trying to pass as parameter):

> Beginning deployment of assembly SolutionName.dll to server localhost : DATABASE
>
> The following error might appear if you deploy a SQL CLR project that was built for a version of the .NET Framework that is incompatible with the target instance of SQL Server: "Deploy error SQL01268: CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly failed because assembly failed verification". To resolve this issue, open the properties for the project, and change the .NET Framework version.
>
> c:\****** name.dll : Deploy error : Could not create a type for parameter System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.96
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Anyone can give me a hand?

Screenshot of XML:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your input XML, on which you are working.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the XML but I had to hide most of it due to company's data being sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your xmldoc.load holds the secret.  What if you just passed the xml as string to the clr procedure.  Then you could create the xmlDoc and load it inside the clr off the string.

If that doesn't work this thread seemed to be close to what you were talking about:[CLR Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533745/197684)

I couldn't say on the error...but the string method above may resolve your issue there.